# Opera 12 and jQuery parent selector

Tags: jquery, opera

This snippet of code is running really strange in Opera 12.
**parent** element is just **ul** and this is what Firefox and Chrome returns.
In Opera **$(this).parent()** is returning **Window** object.

Any ideas? jQuery version is 1.7.2

```
JS
    $('.addTrait').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        trait = $('li.trait.template').clone().removeClass('template');
        parent = $(this).parent();
        $(parent).after(trait);
        trait.show();
    });


HTML
<ul class="sortable traits">
    <li class="trait">
    <div class="well slim">
        <input class="trait name" type="text" name="trait[%s][name]" value=""/>
        <input class="trait id" type="hidden" name="trait[%s][id]" value=""/>
        <input class="trait parent" type="hidden" name="trait[%s][parent]" />
        <a href="" class="addTrait icon-plus"></a>
        <a href="" class="removeTrait icon-remove"></a>
    </div>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<li class="trait template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="well slim">
    <input class="trait name" type="text" name="trait[%s][name]" value=""/>
    <input class="trait id" type="hidden" name="trait[%s][id]" value=""/>
    <input class="trait parent" type="hidden" name="trait[%s][parent]" />
    <a href="" class="addTrait icon-plus"></a>
    <a href="" class="removeTrait icon-remove"></a>
    </div>                
    <ul>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: you should use `on()` instead of `live()` : `$('body').on('click', '.addTrait', function(e) ...)`

Comment: Please post your markup as well

Comment: added markup, console.log($(this)) returns proper **<a href="" class="addTrait icon-plus"></a>** element

Comment: Did you declare your `parent` with `var` somewhere?

Comment: now, but thanks for idea. **var parent = $(this).parent();** fixes this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make it a habit declaring your variables as local. It's not only for fixing bugs like that one, it's for performance optimization too. Take these two snippets, for example:

```
function foo() {
  function bar() {
    var someUrl = 'http://example.com';
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function() { ... };
  }
}

function foo() {
  function bar() {
    someUrl = 'http://example.com';
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function() { ... };
  }
}
```

As you see, in both snippets JS had to evaluate `someUrl` expression when calling `$.getJSON`.

In the first one this variable is declared as local to `bar` function, so its look-up will be very quick.

In the second one, though, this variable name actually refers to a property of global (`window`) object. But JS doesn't know that: it still has to go all the way up the scope chain - just to fail and fallback to accessing `window.someUrl` instead.

Of course, the difference is (usually) negligible when dealing with one or two variables. But usually there are dozens of them, and this constant walking up the scope chain (and resorting to the property access in the end) can have a dramatic impact on the performance of your script.

Comment: Without `eval` or `with` in a parent scope you don't need to walk the scope-chain — you can just jump to the global scope as you know it isn't in any intervening scope.

Comment: How would JS know that it's not in any intervening scope in the second snippet without examining these scopes first?

Comment: Yes, it has to examine them, but it can be done statically (once) and doesn't need to be done at runtime for each execution, so the cost is amortized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @raina77ow in the comments, you need to define `parent` as being a local variable. Opera forbids changing `parent` on the global object (various plugins look at various things to check what origin they are running on for the sake of security, but inevitably overwriting `parent` would break that).